# Cannot access my API key for Custom Search in Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I am trying to get my API key for the new Google Custom Search API.

When I go to Cloud Console->APIs & ath->APIs->Custom Search API->Overview, I get an older dashboard (I believe) for the Cloud console, where I see "API Access". When I hit that, I get redirected to "Cloud Console->APIs & ath->Registered apps", where I cannot see an API key.

How can I get my API key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

It seems that if you register your app as "Native", you do not receive an API key by default. I've had to register my app as "Web" to see an API key.

Alternative:
Access the [old dashboard](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect#project%3a%3CYOUR_PROJECT_ID%3E%3aaccess) and at the "Simple API Access" click "Create new server key"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a direct link: https://cloud.google.com/console?redirected=true#/project/HERE_YOUR_PROJECT_ID/apiui/app?show=allapp

(Remember to replace the project id).

If the key is not there, go back to the APIs & Auth > APIs tab and check if the Custom Search API is ON (green).

Answer (score 0):

The API key is available in the,

- Cloud Console -> APIs & auth -> Credentials -> Public API access